# aspnet_regiis -lk is not listing the site I need

Tags: iis

I am trying to release a site to run under framework 4 on a server that also hosts framework 2 sites.

By default the App has defaulted to framework 2, but when I try to change it's framework to 4 I get a message saying that the following action will cause the iis to reset.

The problem I have is there are serveral active sites that I do not want to interupt with a restart.

The message goes on to say you can avoid restarting by running the following:

`aspnet_regiis -norestart -s [IIS Virtual Path]`

I have been attempting to find the site virtual path but when I run `aspnet_regiis -lk` the site I am after does not appear to be listed.

My first thoughts were that it has something to do with the app pool?, but I'm sure I saw sites that are inactive listed, and after creating a basic site to get it to run under framework 2, the site still did not appear in the `-lk` list.

Can anyone tell me if there is an alternative location to the `-lk` that I can find the specific information realating to the IIS Virtual Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

site logs is the key.

After attempting to browse for the css of the site, a log was generated.

luckily we log local to each site, so within the location for the site's logs was another directory which started with `W3SVC` followed by a number.

So I tried this number as part of the virtual path `W3SVC\[number]` and my site started serving framework 4.

I had to go in and make sure it was running the right scripts and pool etc. but the hard part of trying to get my site working on framework 4 without having restart the entire iis server is now possible, which I am glad about.